# Alarm system built with Raspberry Pi + Sonoff RF bridge

Tags: raspberry-pi, ups

I am developing a personal project at the end of which I should be able to build a sort of homemade alarm system.

All this should be proof against voltage drops / failures, the whole circuit will be inside a "box" that I will print with a 3D printer. To be precise, the project foresees these components:

- Raspberry Pi 0 with Domoticz (80 mA / 0.4 W)
- Sonoff RF Bridge with Tasmota (30 ~ 200mA / 3.0 ~ 3.6V)
- Buzzer
- Step up circuit (optional)

I'm looking for a circuit that works as an "UPS / backup battery", which allows me to keep the system running for as long as possible (1h would be the top.)

A PC UPS (just to be clear) must be excluded as a solution, power banks apparently are not good as manufacturers advise against charging them and powering devices at the same time. I have tried circuits like this but they are very poor, the battery does not hold up and unfortunately the charge readings through the GPII are not realistic.

Comment: So that basically rules out a circuit for a ups then! Neither should you expect folk to guess what current consumption or current profile you might have. If you can't work it out then nobody here can guess at it accurately. Printing something with a 3D printer has got nothing to do with this question (as far as I can tell) and serves only to confuse the issue. Stick to what you are trying to do and finally, ask a specific question; this is a Q and A site and so you supply a valid Q and someone will attempt to provide a valid A.

Comment: Product "shopping" questions (as well as searches for external resource or design materials) are not on topic here.  Realistically, it would be more practical to base your system design around something with less delicate filesystem state than a pi, and preferably having meaningful poweer management such that it can enter low power sleep modes while staying responsive to important events.  If you really want to pursue this there are add-ons that *claim* to offer such capability for a pi, though they would need thorough independent evaluation, and as before, are *off topic* here.

Comment: Crossposted to/from https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118577/alarm-system-built-with-raspberry-sonoff-rf-bridge